# UPS API Error Code 9370701

Tags: python, xml, api, soap, ups

I'm building a python app using the UPS Shipping API. On sending the request (see below) I keep getting the following error:

```
UPS Error 9370701: Invalid processing option.
```

I'm not sure what this means and there isn't much more info in the API documentation. Could someone help me figure out what's going wrong here or give some more information about the cause of this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:ns0="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/Common/v1.0" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:security="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/UPSS/v1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.ups.com/XMLSchema/XOLTWS/FreightShip/v1.0" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header>
      <security:UPSSecurity>
         <security:UsernameToken>
            <security:Username>winkerVSbecks</security:Username>
            <security:Password>myPassword</security:Password>
         </security:UsernameToken>
         <security:ServiceAccessToken>
            <security:AccessLicenseNumber>myLicenseNumber</security:AccessLicenseNumber>
         </security:ServiceAccessToken>
      </security:UPSSecurity>
   </SOAP-ENV:Header>
   <ns1:Body>
      <ns2:FreightShipRequest>
         <ns2:Request>
            <ns0:RequestOption>1</ns0:RequestOption>
            <ns0:RequestOption>Shipping</ns0:RequestOption>
         </ns2:Request>
         <ns2:Shipment>
            <ns2:ShipFrom>
               <ns2:Name>Adobe</ns2:Name>
               <ns2:Address>
                  <ns2:AddressLine>560 Front St. W</ns2:AddressLine>
                  <ns2:AddressLine></ns2:AddressLine>
                  <ns2:City>Toronto</ns2:City>
                  <ns2:StateProvinceCode>ON</ns2:StateProvinceCode>
                  <ns2:PostalCode>M5V1C1</ns2:PostalCode>
                  <ns2:CountryCode>CA</ns2:CountryCode>
               </ns2:Address>
               <ns2:Phone>
                  <ns2:Number>6478340000</ns2:Number>
               </ns2:Phone>
            </ns2:ShipFrom>
            <ns2:ShipperNumber>535T8T</ns2:ShipperNumber>
            <ns2:ShipTo>
               <ns2:Name>Apple</ns2:Name>
               <ns2:Address>
                  <ns2:AddressLine>313 Richmond St. E</ns2:AddressLine>
                  <ns2:AddressLine></ns2:AddressLine>
                  <ns2:City>Toronto</ns2:City>
                  <ns2:StateProvinceCode>ON</ns2:StateProvinceCode>
                  <ns2:PostalCode>M5V4S7</ns2:PostalCode>
                  <ns2:CountryCode>CA</ns2:CountryCode>
               </ns2:Address>
               <ns2:Phone>
                  <ns2:Number>4164530000</ns2:Number>
               </ns2:Phone>
            </ns2:ShipTo>
            <ns2:PaymentInformation>
               <ns2:Payer>
                  <ns2:Name>Spiderman</ns2:Name>
                  <ns2:Address>
                     <ns2:AddressLine>560 Front St. W</ns2:AddressLine>
                     <ns2:City>Toronto</ns2:City>
                     <ns2:StateProvinceCode>ON</ns2:StateProvinceCode>
                     <ns2:PostalCode>M5V1C1</ns2:PostalCode>
                     <ns2:CountryCode>CA</ns2:CountryCode>
                  </ns2:Address>
                  <ns2:ShipperNumber>535T8T</ns2:ShipperNumber>
                  <ns2:AttentionName>He-Man</ns2:AttentionName>
                  <ns2:Phone>
                     <ns2:Number>6478343039</ns2:Number>
                  </ns2:Phone>
               </ns2:Payer>
               <ns2:ShipmentBillingOption>
                  <ns2:Code>10</ns2:Code>
               </ns2:ShipmentBillingOption>
            </ns2:PaymentInformation>
            <ns2:Service>
               <ns2:Code>308</ns2:Code>
            </ns2:Service>
            <ns2:HandlingUnitOne>
               <ns2:Quantity>16</ns2:Quantity>
               <ns2:Type>
                  <ns2:Code>PLT</ns2:Code>
               </ns2:Type>
            </ns2:HandlingUnitOne>
            <ns2:Commodity>
               <ns2:CommodityID>22</ns2:CommodityID>
               <ns2:Description>These are some fancy widgets!</ns2:Description>
               <ns2:Weight>
                  <ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                     <ns2:Code>LBS</ns2:Code>
                  </ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                  <ns2:Value>511.25</ns2:Value>
               </ns2:Weight>
               <ns2:Dimensions>
                  <ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                     <ns2:Code>IN</ns2:Code>
                  </ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                  <ns2:Length>1.25</ns2:Length>
                  <ns2:Width>1.2</ns2:Width>
                  <ns2:Height>5</ns2:Height>
               </ns2:Dimensions>
               <ns2:NumberOfPieces>1</ns2:NumberOfPieces>
               <ns2:PackagingType>
                  <ns2:Code>PLT</ns2:Code>
               </ns2:PackagingType>
               <ns2:CommodityValue>
                  <ns2:CurrencyCode>USD</ns2:CurrencyCode>
                  <ns2:MonetaryValue>265.2</ns2:MonetaryValue>
               </ns2:CommodityValue>
               <ns2:FreightClass>60</ns2:FreightClass>
               <ns2:NMFCCommodityCode>566</ns2:NMFCCommodityCode>
            </ns2:Commodity>
            <ns2:Reference>
               <ns2:Number>
                  <ns2:Code>PM</ns2:Code>
                  <ns2:Value>1651651616</ns2:Value>
               </ns2:Number>
               <ns2:NumberOfCartons>5</ns2:NumberOfCartons>
               <ns2:Weight>
                  <ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                     <ns2:Code>LBS</ns2:Code>
                  </ns2:UnitOfMeasurement>
                  <ns2:Value>2</ns2:Value>
               </ns2:Weight>
            </ns2:Reference>
         </ns2:Shipment>
      </ns2:FreightShipRequest>
   </ns1:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the

```
<ns0:RequestOption>Shipping</ns0:RequestOption>
```

from your request.  The Freight Webservice only allows for numeric request options.  "1" for Ground and "2" for Air.

Answer (score 0):

If you update the RequestOption to '1' instead of 1, it should work. It did for me.

NOTE: I got this error while using rest/JSON.